# Prove the discontinuity of $f$ at origin.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

> Prove the discontinuity of $f $ at origin  $ f(x,y)=\begin{cases}\frac{x^2-xy}{x+y},&\text{if $(x,y)\neq(0,0)$} \\ 0,&(x,y) \>\ = (0,0)\end{cases}$ .
>
> Also show that $f $ has  partial
>   derivatives at every point including the origin.

I am not able to show discontinuity itself. Because when I substitute $y=mx$ the function is going to zero. Even with the substitution $x = r\cos(\theta),y=r\sin(\theta)$ the function is going to zero . How to prove discontinuity?

I can prove partial derivative existence myself.

Comment: The function is not well defined, because $x+y = 0$ if $x = -y$, so the definition does not make sense at $(-1,1)$ for example. Is it a printing mistake?

Answer (score 1):

As Olof pointed out, this is not well-defined when $y=-x$. Let's ignore
this problem and introduce new variables $u=x+y$ and $v=x-y$. Then
$$\frac{x^2-xy}{x+y}=\frac{(u+v)v}{2u}=\frac v2+\frac{v^2}{2u}.$$
Approaching the origin on a curve $(u,v)=(t,t)$ gives a limit zero, while
on the curve $(u,v)=(t^3,t)$ gives limit infinity. You can translate these
paths back into $(x,y)$-coordinates if you so desire.